# When does $({\bf x}^\mathrm{T}{\bf y})(A{\bf z})=({\bf x}^\mathrm{T}A{\bf y}){\bf z}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Under what conditions is $({\bf x}^\mathrm{T}{\bf y})(A{\bf z})=({\bf x}^\mathrm{T}A{\bf y}){\bf z}$? I tried to see if there was any way to determine the conditions through index notation, but that just leaves me at $x_iy_iA_{jk}z_k$ with nowhere to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks! For now I treat $A$ as a matrix and the remaining as vectors, with appropriate dimensions that allow for the products to be taken.

Comment: What are $x,y,z$ and $A$?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães hi, they are usual vectors and matrix, with the only constraint on dimensions being that they are appropriate for the relevant products to be taken.

Comment: I think that one condition is that $A$ is square, It's necessary to have a result for $x^{T}\, Ay$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming $A$ is $n\times n$ and $\bf x,y,z$ are $n\times 1$ for some natural $n$.)

Note that if we instead write
$$
(A{\bf z})({\bf x}^\mathrm{T}{\bf y})={\bf z}({\bf x}^\mathrm{T}A{\bf y})
$$
then all multiplications involved are actually standard matrix multiplications. And dropping the parentheses (which are no longer needed) we see that it is not actually $A$ and $\bf y$ that commute, but $A$ and ${\bf zx}^T$.

More generally, some elementary manipulations of the above equation tells us that we have equality iff $\bf y$ is in the kernel of the *commutator*
$$
[A,{\bf zx}^T]=A{\bf z x}^T-{\bf zx}^TA
$$

Comment: It might be worth adding that the matrices of the form $zx^T$ linearly span the space of all matrices, so if $A$ commutes with all of these, then $A$ lies in the center of the algebra of matrices, which consists only of the scalar matrices

Comment: @Ruy The problem does not quantify the variables. We do not know whether we need to find an $A$ that works for all $\bf x, y, z$, or if we are given $\bf x, y, z$ and must find all $A$ that work, or any other combination. As the problem states just "under what condition", I think my answer is taken more or less as far as it can go.

Comment: this is the most convincing answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Setting $c_1 = x^T y$ and $c_2 = x^T Ay$, your equation becomes $c_1 Az = c_2 z$. Assuming that $c_1 \neq 0$, this means $Az = (c_2 / c_1)z$ and $c_2 / c_1$ is an eigenvalue. If $c_1 = 0$, then you get $c_2 z = 0$, so either $c_2 = 0$ or $z = 0$. Are these the kinds of conditions you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, are these the most general conditions which allow A and y to commute?

Comment: I mean it is an exhaustive argument. You might be able to simplify from the condition of $c_2 / c_1$ being an eigenvalue of $A$, but I'm not sure.  Could you clarify your comment?

Answer (score 0):

This condition can never be true:

Let $x,y,z$ be $n$- dimensional vectors.

For $(x^Ty)(Az)$ to be defined, $A$ would need to be an $1 \times n$ matrix.

For $(x^T A y)z$ to be defined, then $A$ would need to be an $n \times n$ matrix.

So, for the same $A$ you can't have that $(x^Ty)(Az) = (x^T A y)z$, because if one is defined, then the other is not

Comment: Hi, why must A be a 1xn matrix in the first case? Isn’t $x^Ty$ a scalar, so A can be a nxn matrix too?

Comment: No, $x^T y$ is not a scalar. It's an $1 \times 1$ matrix @user107224

Comment: You can multiply a scalar with an $2 \times 2 $ matrix, but you can't multiply an $1 \times 1$ matrix with an $2 \times 2$ matrix. A scalar and a $1 \times 1$ matrix are different objects. @user107224

Comment: ?? $x^{T} y = \sum_{i}^{N}   x_iy_i$

Comment: You mean $[x^T y]_{ij} = \sum _{k = 1}^{n} x_{ki} y_{kj}$. That is the value of the entry of the matrix, not the resoult of the product @Simone

Comment: And also, by definition: Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix and $B$ be an $m \times p$ matrix, then $AB$ is an $n \times p$ MATRIX with entries: $[AB]_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^m a_{ik} b_{kj}$ @Simone

Comment: I don't think you're right. Plus since we can identify the set of all matrices $m \times n$ with $\mathbb R^{mn}$ then we can denote the space $M_{1 \times 1 }$ with $\mathbb R$

Comment: You are right, $M_{n \times m}$ is very similar to $\mathbb R^{nm}$ but they are not the same set! It's wrong to write: $M_{n \times m} = \mathbb R^{nm}$. Insead you say: $M_{n \times m} \simeq \mathbb R^{nm}$ (They are isomorphic). The same way, it is wrong to write $M_{1 \times 1} = \mathbb R$ because that is not true, there is a diference between a scalar and a matrix. Insead it is correct to write $M_{1 \times 1} \simeq \mathbb R$ @Simone

Comment: You can identify the $1 \times 1$ matrices with the scalars, but you do need to be careful. E.g. viewing $x^Ty$ as a scalar, $(x^T y) (Az)$ is defined, but associativity doesn't work. For example, rearranging parentheses to $x^T(yA)z$ doesn't even make sense since $yA$ is not defined. The problem goes away if you move the $(x^Ty)$ to the other side: $(Az)(x^Ty)$ is associative because now the dimensions or each adjacent pair of factors are compatible for matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Bungo that's what I'm saying: $A$ need not be a $1 \times n$ matrix since you can identify $x^{T} y$ as a scalar.

Comment: This is not correct. $A$ can be any $m \times n$ matrix.